# HTML Sketchapp - how to use it properly after intall

Tags: html, github, sketchapp

Trying to use the HTML Sketchapp, specifically turning HTML elements into Sketch symbols ( https://github.com/brainly/html-sketchapp-style-guide ). I installed the npm package already. I'm just confused if I'm suppose to run the following command lines (below) while I'm in my in local folder that has the HTML file containing HTML elements OR if I'm missing another step.

```
npm i
npm run build
npm run inject
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to run those from the project directory. Do you have Node.js and NPM installed?

Comment: @Chris I do have them installed. When run npm -v or node -v, I do see the versions. When I do CD to the local folder that only has one file (HTML) and perform "npm i", I get the following errors...

npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/xxxxx/package.json'

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/xxxxx/package.json'

npm WARN xxxxx No description

npm WARN xxxxx No repository field.

npm WARN xxxxx No README data

npm WARN xxxxx No license field.

Comment: Sorry, when I said "the project directory" I meant the directory where you downloaded the application from GitHub. Something like `git clone ...`, `cd html-sketchapp-style-guide`, `npm i`, `npm run build`, `npm run inject`.

Comment: No worries at all! So I do have another folder with the "html-sketchapp" folder in it. I CD'ed into the "html-sketchapp" and ran...

`code`
npm i 
npm run build 
npm run inject http://sketchapp.com 
`code`

After running "npm run inject http://sketchapp.com", I get the following errors...

`code`
npm ERR! missing script: inject
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/xxxxx/.npm/_logs/2018-09-10T13_24_59_501Z-debug.log
`code`

Comment: Did you run `npm install` and `npm build` first? The build step creates the `inject.js` script.

Comment: While in the "html-sketchapp" folder, I did perform the install and build. Then I ran the `npm run inject sketchapp.com`. And it seems it can't find inject.js even though it's located in html-sketchapp/e2e